# Android SharedPreferences.Editor putStringSet method not available

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to update a password generator I made to include the ability to save passwords, so I'm using SharedPreferences. I want to put the saved passwords inside a Set, but when I try to save the set using SharedPreferences.Editor's putStringSet method, Eclipse does not recognize it. When I hover over putStringSet in my code, the 2 quick fixes available are "Change to putString(...)" and "add cast to editor", but I don't think either of those helps.

This is what I have:

```
public void save(View v)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    savedPasswords = (Set<String>) getSharedPreferences("savedPasswordsList", 0);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setItems(passwords, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface face, int num)
        {
            savedPasswords.add(passwords[num]);
            editor.putStringSet("savedPasswordsList", savedPasswords);
            editor.commit();
            refreshSavedPasswordsList();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`putStringSet(...)` was added at API 11 (Android v3.0.x onwards). My guess is you're targeting a version below that.

Comment: So there's no way to make an upgrade including that code for versions 2.1, 2.2, or 2.3? Are there any other ways of storing a list of Strings supported for those versions?

Comment: If the v3+ code had been open-sourced by Google, you could have tried copying for your own version of the Editor but it hasn't so there's nothing you can do for pre v3 systems directly using Set<String>. The only thing that you can do is put the passwords separately using `putString(...)`. I'd personally save them as strings with key names such as strPass1, strPass2 etc WHen retrieving them I'd use `getAll()` method of SharedPreferences and iterate the returned `Map` checking to see if the key name 'starts with' strPass and use that to build a `Set<String>`. Painful but it would work.

Comment: omg...so I really wanted to use this, but my phones are 2.3.3 where api lev max is 10 . So i can not use this. Why did not they do this from beginning it is very intuitive that putint and put string is not enough.....

Answer (score 2):

I implemented data storage using putStringSet and then needed to backport it to Gingerbread so I created a small class called JSONSharedPreferences.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


    public class JSONSharedPreferences {
      private static final String PREFIX = "json";

        public static void saveJSONObject(SharedPreferences prefs, String key, JSONObject object) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, object.toString());
            editor.commit();
        }

        public static void saveJSONArray(SharedPreferences prefs, String key, JSONArray array) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, array.toString());
            editor.commit();
        }

        public static JSONObject loadJSONObject(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) throws JSONException {
            return new JSONObject(prefs.getString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, "{}"));
        }

        public static JSONArray loadJSONArray(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) throws JSONException {
            return new JSONArray(prefs.getString(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key, "[]"));
        }

        public static void remove(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            if (prefs.contains(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key)) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.remove(JSONSharedPreferences.PREFIX+key);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
//Below, the code to use putStringSet is commented out. 
//Alternative JSONSharedPreferences is used instead 

//Set<String> trainers = new TreeSet<String>();     
JSONArray jTrainers = new JSONArray();
List<FilteredWorkoutVideo> videos = getAllFilteredVideos(prefs);
for (FilteredWorkoutVideo video : videos) {
    //trainers.add(video.getTrainerName()); 
  jTrainers.put(video.getTrainerName());
}

//e = prefs.edit();
//e.putStringSet(Constants.KEY_ALL_TRAINERS, trainers);
//e.apply();
JSONSharedPreferences.saveJSONArray(prefs, Constants.KEY_ALL_TRAINERS, jTrainers);
```

Answer (score 1):

To work around this issue I created a SharedPreferencesCompat class:

In stores the StringSet in a string **CSV**-style.

It is possible to change ',' used in CVS by another delimiter.

```
public class SharedPreferencesCompat {

  private final static String KEY_DELIMITER = "com.example.delimiter";

  public static void setStringSetDelimiter(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, final String delimiter) {
      final Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putString(KEY_DELIMITER, delimiter);
      editor.commit();
  }

  public static Set<String> getStringSet(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, final String key) {
      final Set<String> out = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
      final String base = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
      if (base != null) {
          out.addAll(Arrays.asList(base.split(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_DELIMITER, ","))));
      }
      return out;
  }

  public static void putStringSet(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, final String key,
        final Set<String> stringSet) {
      final String concat = StringUtils.join(stringSet, sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_DELIMITER, ","));
      final Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putString(key, concat);
      editor.commit();
  }
}
```

**Note**:

It depends on apache StringUtils.join() method.

You can easily swap this out for another one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a old, but I just ran into the same issue and my solution was to use a global HashTable to keep track of my strings, which were actually file names.  I also needed a status associated with with each file, so I implemented the following simple class:

```
    public class Globals
    {
        public static enum SendStatus
        {
            NOT_SENT,
            SEND_SUCCESS,
            SEND_ERROR
        }

        public static volatile Hashtable<String, SendStatus> StoredFilesStatus;

        }
    }
```